# Awk script to count occurrences of a negative value in a column and list related row names

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am trying to write an awk script that would create a list of countries that have a negative value in a column and count them:

**Sample data:**

```
Country, COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5
Poland,  -0.3, 0,   2,  -0.5
Canada,  -1,   1,   1,  -0.4
Italy,    7,  -5,   3,  -0.1
France,   1,   2,  -0.5, 7 
Portugal, 1,   NULL,   4,   1
```

**Desired Output:**

```
2 COL2, Poland, Canada, 
1 COL3, Italy, 
1 COL4, France, 
3 COL5, Poland, Canada, Italy,
```

I have started to write a script, but is not even close to the desired result:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash 

INPUT=./happiness2.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','

awk 'NF==1{next} 
  {country=$1; $1=""; gsub(/[^-]/,"",$0); l=length($0); 
   print country, l;
        }
  }' < $INPUT
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your data has at least one negative value per column. Do you want to output a count of zero for a column with only non-nagative values, or omit it? Do you want the output to strictly folow the columns or is a random order OK?

Answer (score 2):

This reads the column names from the first line, rather than hard code them. It would be helpful to make the output pretty if the extra space in the first line could be removed.

**EDITED:**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# The arrays are
# name, indexed by column number, the names of the columns taken from the first line.
# cl, indexed by the column name, the list of countries for which
#    this column is negative.
# cnt, indexed by column name, the count of the number of countries.
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==1 { for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) { name[i]=$i } ; next }
{
    # loop over the columns
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        # get the value of the column as a number
        v=$i+0
        # move on to the next column if the value is non negative.
        if (v>=0) continue;
        # get the name of the column
        n=name[i]
        # increment the count and add the country onto the list
        cnt[n]++
        cl[n] = cl[n]  $1  ", "
    }
}
END { # At the end, loop over the results.
      for (i in name) {
        # get the column name
        n=name[i]
        # print out the saved data
        printf("%d %s, %s\n",cnt[n]+0, n, cl[n]); }}
```

Note that the order of the output is not well defined.

In general if someone asks for clarification of the question it is helpful to provide it.

Comment: Use `FS=" *, *"` and then you won't have to worry about extra spaces in the first line or anywhere else and can just use `$i` instead of `v` with `v=$i+0` since `$i` will already be a `strnum`.

Comment: @icarus the script works almost perfectly but it does not only count the negative values but also the NULL and 0 values. Could you add a small description to it so that I can understand how to count only the values lover than 0? I was trying to modify your script but with no success. Thank you!

Comment: You should wait for @icarus to respond rather than posting their code on a different forum (https://stackoverflow.com/q/70556142/1745001) and asking about it.

Comment: The post has been edited so that it is clear it contains @icarus script. Thank you Ed!

Comment: Change "if (v>0) continue;" to "if (v>=0) continue;" to not count empty or zero values.

Answer (score 0):

The following starts by deleting all the spaces around the commas  using `sed` (this could be done more carefully using e.g. `csvformat -S` if there are header fields containing spaces, but it's good enough for the data provided in the question). The pipeline transposes the data using `datamash`, then outputs the countries that have negative values on each line.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

sed 's/ *, */,/g' file |
datamash -t, transpose |
awk -F, '
    BEGIN { OFS = FS }
    NR == 1 { for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) h[i] = $i; next }
    {
        nf = split($0,a)
        $0 = a[1]

        for (i = 2; i <= nf; ++i)
            if (a[i] < 0) $(NF+1) = h[i]

        if (NF > 1) print NF-1, $0
    }'
```

The `NR == 1` block in the `awk` code executes only for the first line of input from `datamash`.  The output from `datamash` will be

```
Country,Poland,Canada,Italy,France,Portugal
COL2,-0.3,-1,7,1,1
COL3,0,1,-5,2,NULL
COL4,2,1,3,-0.5,4
COL5,-0.5,-0.4,-0.1,7,1
```

This means that the array `h` will contain the headers from the first line.

For all other lines of input from `datamash`, we create output records consisting of the countries whose corresponding number is negative.  We do this by splitting the input line on commas into the array `a`, and then resetting the current record, `$0`, to be `a[1]`, which is one of the `COL` strings.  We then loop over the other entries of `a`, adding the header from `h` te the current record whenever we find a number lower than zero.

We then print the number of fields in the current record (minus one to account for the `COL` string), and the record itself.

Output given the data in the question:

```
2,COL2,Poland,Canada
1,COL3,Italy
1,COL4,France
3,COL5,Poland,Canada,Italy
```

You could change the `print` at the end to

```c
printf "%d\t%s\n", NF-1, $0
```

... if you want to have the first column separated by a tab from the others:

```
2       COL2,Poland,Canada
1       COL3,Italy
1       COL4,France
3       COL5,Poland,Canada,Italy
```

With the following input,

```
COUNTRY NAME, SOCIAL SUPPORT, FREEDOM TO MAKE LIFE CHOICES, GENEROSITY, PERCEPTIONS OF CORRUPTION, POSITIVE AFFECT, NEGATIVE AFFECT, CONFIDENCE IN NATIONAL GOVERNMENT, DEMOCRATIC QUALITY, DELIVERY QUALITY
Afghanistan, 0.49, NULL, -0.11, 0.95, 0.49, 0.37, -0.26, -1.88, -1.43
Albania, 0.63, NULL, -0.03, 0.87, 0.66, 0.33, -0.45, 0.29, -0.13
Algeria, 0.80, NULL, -0.19, 0.69, 0.64, 0.34, 0.24, -0.92, -0.81
Argentina, 0.90, NULL, -0.18, 0.84, 0.80, 0.29, 0.30, 0.35, 0.15
```

... the script produces

```
4,GENEROSITY,Afghanistan,Albania,Algeria,Argentina
2,CONFIDENCE IN NATIONAL GOVERNMENT,Afghanistan,Albania
2,DEMOCRATIC QUALITY,Afghanistan,Algeria
3,DELIVERY QUALITY,Afghanistan,Albania,Algeria
```

Comment: Hello @they! Thank you! It works perfectly fine but I am not sure how to put it into an awk script. I guess the datamash  is not compatible with awk scripts.

Comment: @KlauRau The script in may answer is a shell script which uses `tr`, `datamash` and `awk`. It is not an `awk` script.

Comment: Hello @they ! the awk works almost perfectly but it does not count the negative values only it includes 0 and NULL in the count.

Comment: @KlauRau I don't know what data you are testing on. I'm running this on the data in your question and get the exact results you are asking for.  The output I includes only the counts of the negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of Icarus solution, but here the printing order of columns is in increasing order.

```
awk -F ' *, *' '
NR==1{split($0,a);next}
{
  for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
    if ( $i ~ /^-/ ) {
      col = a[i]
      buf[col] = buf[col] $1 "," OFS
      knt[col]++
    }
}
END {
  for (i=2; i in a; i++) {
    col = a[i]
    if ( knt[col] )
      print knt[col], col",", buf[col]
  }
}
' file

2 COL2, Poland, Canada, 
1 COL3, Italy, 
1 COL4, France, 
3 COL5, Poland, Canada, Italy,
```